# logstash-logger and filtering events

Tags: ruby, logging, logstash

I'm using logstash-logger in a Ruby app. It's great. However, I seem to have a problem that my debug messages are being forwarded, and no setting seems to turn that off. It's increasing my logging requirements by 3 to 5 fold, both increasing the costs and slowing down the app.

Is there a way to filter log messages to eliminate this noise?

I have set in the config.logger_level to :info, but debug messages are still being forwarded.

Any suggestions?

P.s. My config below, is still sending debug messages and info messages.

```
@logstash_logger = ::LogStashLogger.new(
    type: :multi_delegator,
    outputs: [
         { type: :stdout },
         { type: :udp, host: logging_host, port: logging_port }
    ])
@logstash_logger.level = ::Logger::WARN
```

Comment: use a gem like pry-byebug and step through a logger call. this way you'll figure out what's wrong in your setup. it should be easy to configure that. log-levels can be confusing.

Comment: Appreciate your answer, and already done. Its set to Logger::(or warn in this case). But, I'm still seeing debug in the logs.

Comment: There is no "filtering" here. It sends all messages.